# AlarmManager never returns and event for the BroadcastReceiver, how to debug?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

The code below does not throw any errors, nor does it work. When I debug the addInvoiceReminder() method it appears the time is being setup correctly and the AlarmManager is set to go off at the time previously set. Can someone see my flaw? I am not sure why the BroadcastReceiver's onRecieve event never fires.

```
//---adds an invoice reminder when the user successfully adds a sales or expense invoice---
 public void addInvoiceReminder () {
    //---gets a Calendar object with current time---
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     //---sets the calendar object to the reminder dialog date---
     //cal.set(reminder_year, reminder_month, reminder_day);
     cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, DueInvoiceAlarmReceiver.class);
     intent.putExtra("reminder", "Invoice Number: 999999 is due!");         
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

     //---gets the alarm manager service set for the calendar time which is the reminder time---
     AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
 }

 //---Receives the event fired when the reminder date for an invoice is passed---
 public class DueInvoiceAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {        
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       try {
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         String message = bundle.getString("reminder");
         Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();        
        }
     }       
 }
```

Comment: The BroadcastReceiver's onReceive never fires, I have set a debug point in the DueInvoiceAlarmReceiver and it never triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you declare your broadcast reciever in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks, but it was declared. Sorry, forgot to mention that originally.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Calendar cal = cal .getInstance(); cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Because you are trying to receive the time in mill but never set it too it.

Comment: Hmm, no, because when I debug I see the time is set in milliseconds, this is achieved with "cal.getTimeInMillis()" as you can see it in the last line of addInvoiceReminder().

Comment: yeah I am stumped then too. Good luck